# Java loop is not terminating

Tags: java, while-loop

Can someone tell me why this loop is continuous?

```
while(sum !=7 || sum!=pt){
        System.out.println(sum);
        die1.roll();
        die2.roll();
        sum = (die1.getNumber() + die2.getNumber());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The sum of your numbers are "+sum);
}
```

Even if the sum is equal to 7 or the variable pt then the loop keep on going for some reason.

Comment: Change '||' to '&&'.

Answer (score 1):

Change `||` to `&&`.  Your loop will continue while one of the conditions evaluates to true.  In order to make it stop when one becomes true, you need to change your boolean operator.